# Cannot Redirect SignUp Button to Sign Up page since Unable to start activity ComponentInfo error occurs

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a login Activity. In login Activity, I have to enter Mobile number and password and then click the Login button.

Here is my `activity_login.xml`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    tools:context="com.myayubo.LoginActivity"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayouttxtayubo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textAyubo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ayubo"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:typeface="normal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="35dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayouttxtexplorer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayouttxtayubo"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textExplore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Explore places nearby you"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobileNo"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                >

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
                android:text="Login"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:alpha="0.5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fbbtn"
                android:text="Connect with Facebook"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#ADD8E6"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fbbtn"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="or Sign Up"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And Here is my `LoginActivity.java`

```
package com.myayubo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.myayubo.services.MessageHandler;
import com.myayubo.services.ServiceHandler;

import org.json.JSONObject;


public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final static String URL = "";

    public static String Uid;

    private EditText contact;

    private EditText password;

    private Button login;

    private Button fbBtn;

    private TextView signUp;

    private boolean errorStatus;

    private ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileNo);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        fbBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbbtn);
        signUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUp);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!ServiceHandler.isOnline(getApplicationContext())){
                    MessageHandler.showMessage("No network connection",
                            getApplicationContext());
                }

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Looper.prepare();

                        String mobile = contact.getText().toString();
                        String passwrd = password.getText().toString();

                        if (mobile.length() == 0){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    MessageHandler.showMessage(
                                            "Please Enter Your Contact Number",
                                            getApplicationContext());
                                    errorStatus = true;
                                }
                            });
                            ;
                        }

                        if (passwrd.length() == 0){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    MessageHandler.showMessage(
                                            "Please Enter Your Password",
                                            getApplicationContext());
                                    errorStatus = true;
                                }
                            });
                            ;
                        }

                        String jsonStr = null;
                        if (!errorStatus) {
                            if (!ServiceHandler.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                                MessageHandler.showMessage("No network connection",
                                        getApplicationContext());
                            } else {
                                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


                                // notify user you are online
                                try{
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {

                                        }
                                    });
                                    ;

                                    jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL + "/" + mobile + "/"
                                            + passwrd, ServiceHandler.GET);
                                    System.out.println(URL + "/" + mobile + "/"
                                            + passwrd);

                                }
                                catch (Exception e){

                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            MessageHandler.showMessage("No network connection",
                                                    getApplicationContext());

                                        }
                                    });
                                    ;
                                }
                            }

                            if (jsonStr != null) {
                                String status = "";
                                String msg = "";

                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {

                                        }
                                    });
                                    ;

                                    if (jsonObj != null
                                            && jsonObj.has("status")) {
                                        status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                                        msg = jsonObj.getString("message");
                                        if(jsonObj.has("uid"))
                                            Uid = jsonObj.getString("uid");
                                        System.out.println(jsonObj);
                                        if (status.equals("OK")) {
                                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                                    getBaseContext(),
                                                    ExtractMenu.class);
                                            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                                        } else if (status.equals("ERROR")) {
                                            final String errorMsg = msg;
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    MessageHandler
                                                            .showMessage(
                                                                    errorMsg,
                                                                    getApplicationContext());
                                                }
                                            });
                                            ;
                                        } else {
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    MessageHandler
                                                            .showMessage(
                                                                    "Oops..! something wrong with the service. Please try again Later.",
                                                                    getApplicationContext());
                                                }
                                            });
                                            ;
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out
                                            .println("Creation of json object failed");
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });


        signUp.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, sign_up.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Looks like something is wrong here. Because, when I'm trying to run this code, my app crashes. It shows the following error.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

But, without intent for signUp button it works.

Here is my logcat.

```
11-05 10:36:58.359  27532-27532/com.myayubo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myayubo, PID: 27532
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myayubo.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:57)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please some1 tell me what to do with this error.

Thaks in advance.

-Edit -

Here is the Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myayubo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="Ayubo" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ExtractMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_extract_menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".sign_up"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: Add activity to AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting NPE because you are trying to add view which is not in your xml file

```
signUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUp);
```

there is no text view in your xml with this id. check it out if you remove this your code will run perfectly

Comment: Oh! how silllly I am. Thankks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` Because there isn't any `TextView` with id `signUp` in `activity_login.xml` layout.

In your onCreate Method

```
signUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUp);
```

But as your `activity_login.xml` does not contain `TextView` with `id` `signUp` it **return null**,

And again you try to set listener on that `TextView` which is null so `NullPointerException`

```
signUp.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Looks like  you fogot to set id here,

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/text2"   //android:id="@+id/signUp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/fbbtn"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:text="or Sign Up"
      android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```